# Best way to query/receive device hostname, IP address and username in an enterprise environment

Tags: python, security, active-directory, network-programming

I am a security analyst..and Python newbie that constantly needs to find the following 3 pieces of information on end users during incident investigations at work:

1.Their device hostname
2.The IP address associated with the device
3.Their login username

I don't even know how to begin creating a script that would provide this information, but I'm thinking that it would prompt me to input 1 of the 3 piece of info I mentioned above and then print out the other 2 pieces. Beyond the prompt part below, I'm stuck..

```
#!/usr/bin/python

print "Please paste in one of the following pieces of information.."

print "\n"

print "1. Device hostname"
print "2. IP address"
print "3. Username"

print "\n"

str = raw_input()
```

I've seen a few posts that detail how to pull various bits of info on a system locally, but not remotely. Does anyone know how I'd go about building this type of script in Python?

Comment: Are you specifically trying to do this in Python or are other non-Python solutions acceptable?

Comment: I'd like to do it in Python, but I'm willing to try any other language as well

Answer (score 0):

There are existing command line tools that you can use like: `dig`, the `host` command, and `nslookup` which will all do DNS lookups for hostnames and IP addresses. The request for "username" doesn't seem meaningful. More than one user can log in to a single machine, so I'm not sure how you plan on gathering that piece of information unless you allow for multiple return values.

Also here's a Perl one-liner that will do an IP to name resolution (reverse DNS lookup):

```
perl -e 'use Socket qw(getnameinfo inet_aton pack_sockaddr_in NI_NUMERICSERV); my $ip = inet_aton($ARGV[0]); my $addr = pack_sockaddr_in(80, $ip); my ($err, $hostname) = getnameinfo($addr, NI_NUMERICSERV); print "$hostname\n"'
```

The script assumes a single argument on the command line.

Here's a script that does the same thing in the forward DNS direction, printing all IPs:

```
perl -e 'use Socket qw(getaddrinfo getnameinfo NI_NUMERICSERV NI_NUMERICHOST); my ($err, @res) = getaddrinfo($ARGV[0], "www", {socktype => SOCK_STREAM}); for my $r (@res) { my ($err, $ip) = getnameinfo($r->{addr}, NI_NUMERICHOST | NI_NUMERICSERV); print "$ip\n";}'
```

It also assumes a single command line argument.

If you want a Python solution, this will get you started using the [`gevent`](http://www.gevent.org/gevent.resolver_ares.html) library:

```
import gevent.resolver_ares
from gevent.socket import AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM

def resolve(fqdn):
    resolver = gevent.resolver_ares.Resolver()
    results = resolver.getaddrinfo(
        fqdn, 0, family=AF_INET, socktype=SOCK_STREAM)
    return results[0][-1][0]
```

This only does a forward resolution, but you should be able to modify it based on the Perl code to get a working reverse resolution as well. You can also use the built-in [`socket.getaddrinfo`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.getaddrinfo) instead, but if you plan on doing this for a large number of machines, I'd recommend the `gevent` library.